# bash + why script bash is killed during ambari-agent stop

Tags: python, bash, shell, kill, ambari

I am using the following simple script in order to stop and start the ambari agent on linux machine `rhel 7.6`

```
more /tmp/script

#!/bin/bash

ambari-agent start
sleep 10
ambari-agent stop

echo "start stop ambari agent ended"
```

example

```
bash script


Verifying Python version compatibility...
Using python  /usr/bin/python
Checking for previously running Ambari Agent...
/run/ambari-agent/ambari-agent.pid found with no process. Removing 25236...
Checking ambari-common dir...
Starting ambari-agent
Verifying ambari-agent process status...
Ambari Agent successfully started
Agent PID at: /run/ambari-agent/ambari-agent.pid
Agent out at: /var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-agent.out
Agent log at: /var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-agent.log
Verifying Python version compatibility...
Using python  /usr/bin/python
Found ambari-agent PID: 25810
Stopping ambari-agent
Killed
```

as we can see from some unclear reason the script itself is killed when `ambari-agent stop` performed 
and therefore `echo "stop start ambari agent ended"` , never implemented

any idea why this happens?

Comment: Not able to find documentation of this utility. But it is killing process based on PID.   can you add `ps -ef| grep  'script'` before kill command and check if PID of the script and this utility

Comment: @jessica : Perhaps this problem is better reported at the [Ambari Issue Tracker](https://ambari.apache.org/issue-tracking.html), since it smells like a bug in ambari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently experienced quite a bit of weirdness in a recent RHEL7 ambari cluster role out.  The weirdness was coming from higher level configurations in the operating system based on the default role out (azure).  It's a long shut but maybe the bash execution is just too long and getting killed?